# SOAP Transaction - is it synced?

Tags: android, soap, apache-axis, ksoap2

enter code hereI have a basic question regarding an implementation using a Axis2 web service and Android KSOAP2 client.

I have an API of the server that gets unviewed entries from a table
Table: key,cul1..culn, culViewes - bit if was viewed or not.

I implemented the GetUnViewedAPI as followed (in the service):

```
public int[] getUnviewed()
{
    ... getting all unviewed ids...
    ... marking them as viewed...
    ... return the unviewed ids..
}
```

What if connection is lost in the middle (with the mobile client)?
Then the unviewed entries will not be viewed...since were marked as viewed but result did not get to the user.

Should user send ACK for each of the ids (or ack on all togather...)?
Or... ????
How it is usually handled?

Yoav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this up. First you get all the unviewed ones to the user. Then the user has to actively e.g. do a select all and pressed a viewed button or so and then you push back to the server what was viewed and mark it as such.

If you do it all automatically you have no idea if the users actually ever saw it or received it for that matter. Theoretically Soap has transaction support as part of one of the ws* standards but I doubt that would be useful in your use case. I also dont think ksoap2 android supports them (and I am the project owner..)

Comment: I see yout point.... What I do - is the Viewed flag - is actually a flag to indicate if entry has been D/L to the device. Since I store in the device these entries so will not need to query all the time lots of data from the server. So as I understand - you suggest to send messsage to server after each entry I save in the local DB? or for all togather... And only then mark it as viewed(D/L) in the server... In this case I will need to check when D/L and inserting to DB if an entry exists (in case that the "mark-view/downloaded" request to server might have been lost (if connection was lost)..

Comment: Correct. You are basically manually creating a transaction. You could try to use WS-Transaction or so but it might be harder to figure out and implement..